# jekyll: How remove first / from permalink

Tags: jekyll, permalinks

in _config.yml I setup permalink
but still in generating files i get '/' on start url

```
<a href="/........"
```

how removing this first '/' ?

Comment: See here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-control-urls-and-links-in-jekyll

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner this link is about writing post not for writing url in html ;(

Comment: Well, your question is not very clear. What did you try/search so far? Is there a specific reason you want to remove the first slash?

Comment: yes, I have reason for remove first slash, all my web site must be relative. If my question is not good, please edit it. My english is not perfect.

Comment: Relative paths start with a slash: `www.example.com/posts.html` (absolute path) - `/posts.html` (relative path). Are we talking about this?